# OSPFのL2SWを挟んだ経路交換について

Tags: network

下記画像のRouterA,B,CでOSPFによる経路交換を行いたいです。

この場合、下記画像の赤枠部分は同一ネットワーク、同一VLANでないと経路交換は行えないのでしょうか？
[image: opsf]